# How to determine if a string is numeric in ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

I'm trying to validate input in ksh, and would like to know the easiest way to determine if a string is a valid number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a go with :

```
    case $INPUT in
        +([0-9])*(.)*([0-9]) )
              # Variable is numeric
              ;;
        *) 
              # Nope, not numeric
              ;;

esac
```

Comment: Does ksh put wildcards before instead of after, as in a "regular" regular expression?

Comment: This solution seems to consider 123...99 as numeric

Comment: then just use the ? operator that matches 0 or 1 repetitions of the re like this  +([0-9])?(.)*([0-9])

Answer (score 2):

Simpler, if you just want to know if the string is composed of digits:

```
case $INPUT in
    [0-9][0-9]* )
          # Variable contains only digits
          ;;
    *) 
          # Variable contains at least one non-digit
          ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this answer here (https://www.unix.com/302299284-post9.html) and it does work in ksh-88 in Solaris 10 for integers:

```
x=2763
if [[ $x == +([0-9]) ]]; then
    print integer
else
    print nope
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixes FreudianSlip's answer to include optional, leading "-" or "+" sign, allow decimal numbers that begin with "." (no leading 0), and exclude numbers containing multiple "." (e.g. "12...34"):

```
case $INPUT in
    {,1}([-+])+([0-9]){,1}(.)*([0-9])|{,1}([-+]).+([0-9]))
          # Variable is numeric
          ;;
    *) 
          # Nope, not numeric
          ;;

esac
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string operator in test like so:

```
if [[ "${input%%*( )+([0-9])?(.)*([0-9])}" = "" ]]; then
   print "Is numeric"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ $input -ge 0 -o $input-lt 0 ] 2>/dev/null && echo "numeric"
```

This will check if the input is numeric (positive or negative integer) and print numeric if it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ -z $(print $input | tr -d '[:digit:]') ]]
then
 print "$input is numeric"
fi
```

The -z test operator tests for a null string.

The `tr -d` command removes all digits.

If anything remains after the tr, it is not numeric.